# Will not be just inserted in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I sit in a problem as do that I can not create / throw user information into the database,. It is just as soon as it should insertOnSubmit (UsersAccount); so it will not in any way confirm it.

I get that this error:

Error 1:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'MentorOrdblind_MVC.Models.Konto.UsersAccount' to
>   'MentorOrdblind_MVC.Models.Linq.User'

Error 2:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Linq.Table.InsertOnSubmit(MentorOrdblind_MVC.Models.Linq.User)'
>   has some invalid arguments

**KontoController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateUsers(UsersAccount UsersAccount)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var email = UsersAccount.Email;
        // Checking up whether there is a user with the email.
        var CreateAnAccount = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Email == email);
        if (CreateAnAccount != null)
        {

            UsersAccount.Email = email;//email
            UsersAccount.PassWordHash = UsersAccount.PassWordHash;//password
            UsersAccount.Firstname = UsersAccount.Firstname;//firstname
            UsersAccount.Lastname = UsersAccount.Lastname;//lastname
            UsersAccount.PhoneNumber = UsersAccount.PhoneNumber;//phonenumber

            //true - False
            UsersAccount.Newsletter = Convert.ToBoolean(UsersAccount.Newsletter);//newsletter

            //which some Fk users have chosen.
            UsersAccount.fk_role = Convert.ToInt32(UsersAccount.Roles);// what's roles
            UsersAccount.fk_package = 0;//package
            UsersAccount.fk_sex = Convert.ToInt32(UsersAccount.Sexs);//sex
            UsersAccount.fk_area = Convert.ToInt32(UsersAccount.Areas);//area
            UsersAccount.fk_Professionals = Convert.ToInt32(UsersAccount.Professionals);//professional

            //age
            UsersAccount.age = Convert.ToDateTime(UsersAccount.age);

            //img users
            UsersAccount.img = "userimg.png";

            // Need to find out what role you have chosen,
            if (UsersAccount.fk_role == 6)
            {
                UsersAccount.Approved = false;
            }
            else
            {
                UsersAccount.Approved = true;
            }

            // should just content into the database.
            db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(UsersAccount);

            // must save the contents.
            db.SubmitChanges(); // save

            // send the person to the log in page.

        }
        else
        {
            //Fremviser en fejl besked hvis der findes en email.
            ViewBag.MessageError = "Denne brugere findes i vores system.";
        }
    }
    //return indhold til siden.
    return View();
}
```

**UsersAccount.cs**

```
public class UsersAccount
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    //email
    [Display(Name = "EmailAddress")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Husk at skriv en email!")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    //password
    [Display(Name = "PassWordHash")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Husk at angiv en adgangskode!")]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage="Den skal have midst 5 tegn!")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage="Vi skal være sikker på du kan husk din kode!")]
    public string PassWordHash { get; set; }

    //fornavn
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Husk dit fornavn")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage="Det skal være mere end 2 tegn!")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage="Tilader ikke så langt navn")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    //efternavn
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Husk dit efternavn")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage="Det skal være mere end 2 tegn!")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage="Kun et enkelt efternavn..")]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    //Om man er tilmeldt eller ej,
    public bool Newsletter { get; set; }

    //list som bruges til Område
    public int fk_area { get; set; }
    public List<Area> Areas { get; set; }

    //list som bruges til Hvilke køn man er?
    public int fk_sex { get; set; }
    public List<Sex> Sexs { get; set; }

    //Fremviser hvilke roller man kan være
    public int fk_role { get; set; }
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    //Viser hvilke fag man kan få hjælp til.
    public int fk_Professionals { get; set; }
    public List<Professional> Professionals { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    //hvilke slags pakke brugere skal have, men den bliver sat til 0 hele tiden ved oprettelse.
    public int fk_package { get; set; }

    //Denne her klare sig selv!!
    //den skal selv opret datetime (Altså tilføj sig selv)
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime creatadate
    {
        get { return DateTime.Now; }
    }

    [Display(Name="Age")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime age { get; set; }

    //Den her bliver sat på true eller false alt efter om man har valgt mentor eller elev/forældre
    public bool Approved { get; set; }

    //Angiver et billede til databasen. (Det kan ikke blive slette).. bare rolig..
    public string img { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Der skal være et telefon nr.")]
    [MinLength(8, ErrorMessage="Vi skal bruge 8 tegn som min.")]
    [MaxLength(8, ErrorMessage="Alle har et telefon nr på 8 tegn.")]
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

}
```

What do I wrong since I just can not insert it in the users tablen?

Comment: `if (CreateAnAccount != null)` should probably be `if (CreateAnAccount == null)`. `CreateAnAccount` will be `null`, if there's no user in the `db.Users` table having the `UsersAccount.Email` email.

Comment: @Dzienny Thanks, yes it's real, but it does still not.

Comment: Well, `InsertOnSubmit` expects a `User` object. `User` is the class created by LINQ-to-SQL, while `UsersAccount` is class (a view model?) you created yourself. You have create a `User` from a `UsersAccount` and save the `User`.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for help! :)